# Publish Python Flask Application on Linux Server

Tags: python, linux, web-services, nginx, flask

I have developed a python flask application and I'm trying to publish it on Linux Server as WebService. It doesn't have any interface it just return string or something like this. I have developed it on Windows and my code was like in the below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=80, debug=True)
```

Then I have connected to linux server via SSH.

I installed my codes to -> /var/www/myapp/code
Then I created a myapp.conf config file to  -> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

```
server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name x.x.x.x;

        root /var/www/myapp/code/main.py;

        passenger_enabled on;
}
```

Then I run "python main.py" in /var/www/myapp/code/ Then I get:

*return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)** 
*socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use*

When I change listen 127.0.0.1:80; to 80 it works but i can't send any request. I'm trying to send via postman as **http ://x.x.x.x:80/myurl**

How can I publish it correctly? I want to serve it on Linux Server and send request from my windows post man application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use  :

```
server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name x.x.x.x;

        root /var/www/myapp/code/main.py;

        passenger_enabled on;
}
```

for change your ip

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work... When I set the app.run(port=80, debug=True) in main.py and set the   listen 0.0.0.0:80 i'm getting "Address already in use". When my app runs on 127.0.0.1:5000 then I set the 0.0.0.0:5000 i get the same error. I can't configure well.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use same port for your flask app and nginx

Use a different port for flask app

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

Also, nginx can't talk to python apps directly, instead you have to proxy the requests to flask server

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        passenger_enabled on;
        location / {
           proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice but when i add proxy_pass line my nginx service throws an error.

Comment: @fordev What error do you see ? It might be due too missing semicolon in the `proxy_pass` line.

Comment: Thanks I overlooked it. But still I can't send request to it. I guess my deploy configuration is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on [@Conans-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66256548/7136415)

Request you to refer the Documentation:- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name _;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
}}
```

Comment: Hi there, yes I have downloaded gunicorn and virtualenv. I created an env for my application. Then I change my config file like yours but also I added server_name x.x.x.x which is where i want to publish it. Then I run the gunicorn as "gunicorn  myapp:app" it works. But when i send a request http://x.x.x.x it doesn't return a value it sends <h4> Http Error:404 Page does Not Exists ! </h4> error